# Proving an inequality with the Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

Given a vector space with a Hermitian dot product defined, prove the following inequality using the Schwarz inequality.

Let $f$ be a complex value function that is continuous within $0 \le x \le 1$,
$$
\left| \int ^1 _0 x^2 f(x) dx \right|^2 \le \frac{1}{3} \int^1_0x^2|f(x)|^2dx
$$

My attempt was to define $g(x) := x^2$ and then define a dot product $(f,g) = \int^1_0 g(x)f(x) dx$ and then proceed to use the Schwarz inequality.

However I ended up with something like $\frac{1}{5} \sqrt{\int^1_0 (f(x))^2 dx}$ on the right side, can someone point me the right way to solving this?

Comment: The square of which function is in the integral on the right?

Comment: @DanielFischer The square is on both functions

Comment: I mean: $x^2\lvert f(x)\rvert^2 = \lvert h(x)\rvert^2$, what is $h$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. Do I find $h$ using the $|x|^2=x\bar{x}$ method?

Comment: $x$ is real and non-negative here, no need for conjugation or absolute value for that. Cauchy-Schwarz gives you $$\left\lvert \int_0^1 a(x)b(x)\,dx\right\rvert^2 \leqslant \int_0^1 \lvert a(x)\rvert^2\,dx \cdot \int_0^1 \lvert b(x)\rvert^2\,dx.$$ Write the right hand side of the inequality in that form.

Comment: @DanielFischer So do I take $a(x)=x^2$ and $b(x)=f(x)$ and write in that form? I tried it and I couldn't get the inequality.

Comment: No. Look at the right hand side to see what you should take for $b$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12839/discussion-between-theonly92-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Start from the right hand side:

$$\frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 x^2\lvert f(x)\rvert^2\,dx = \int_0^1 \lvert x\rvert^2\,dx\cdot \int_0^1 \lvert xf(x)\rvert^2\,dx.$$

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot, I think I got it, let me work out a little...

Comment: Ah, that's even nicer than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1.** For a function $w$ which is almost everywhere positive on $(0,1)$, we can consider the inner product weighted by $w$: $$(f,g)_w:=\int_0^1 f(x) \overline{g(x)} w(x) dx.$$

**Hint 2.** For this inner product, the (Cauchy-)Schwarz(-Bunyakovsky)'s inequality reads like this:

$$\left\vert \int_0^1 f(x) \overline{g(x)} w(x) dx \right\vert^2 \leq \left(\int_0^1 \vert f(x)\vert^2 w(x) dx \right )\cdot \left(\int_0^1 \vert g(x)\vert^2 w(x) dx \right ).$$

**Hint 3.** In structure, this already looks pretty close to what we're trying to show, provided we can find suitable functions $g$ and $w$.

**Hint 4.** Looking at the integrand of the first factor of the RHS, one could try $w(x)=x^2$.

**Hint 5.** The LHS of our Schwarz's inequality looks like the LHS of the desired inequality if we then choose $g(x)=1$.

**Solution.** Since $\int_0^1 x^2 dx =1/3$, with $w(x)=x^2, g(x)=1$, we get indeed $\vert \int _0^1 f(x)x^2 dx \leq \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \vert f(x) \vert^2 x^2 dx$